# How to identify when SIM changed in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, core-telephony

How to find if a user changes his SIM card from his phone(iPhone). we can find "mobileCountryCode,isoCountryCode,mobileCountryCode and mobileNetworkCode" through programatically these are not specific to particular SIM, these are specific to operator, is there any way to identify when user changes his SIM card from his iPhone.

Please any one help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are able to sign up for a notification using `subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier` in 
[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html)

However you will only be notified if the swap occurs while your app is running. You will still be unable to detect if the user changes the SIM to another SIM from the same operator when your app is not running.

Comment: Thank you very much Claus Broch.after registering for a Notification which API should i use to get my phone number or if i sign up how can i get the phone number.

Comment: I don't think you can grab the telephone number through any public API's

Answer (score 1):

Hi tony You can use this for finding sim has been changed or not.

```
NSString *currentIMSINo = CTSIMSupportCopyMobileSubscriberIdentity(NULL);
```