# When SIM is not available how should we handle MFMessageComposeViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, sms, sim-card, core-telephony

I am using MFMessageComposeViewController to send text message via my App.  But I have a problem when we remove the SIM and try to send message.  Is there any delegate available to track whether the message will be sent / not?

Comment: Next time consult [class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html) before you waste time on typing such question.

Comment: Thanks @TheBlack for your comment.  But your suggestion may not work in all cases.  Learn the one given by @Nick Weaver

Comment: I searched for "sim card" in Xcode help and found CTTelephonyNetworkInfo in 15 seconds. Next, I came here, entered "sim card iphone" into search and found [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5245846/how-to-identify-when-sim-changed-in-iphone) You learn how to search before asking questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CTTelephonyNetworkInfo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009594) class of the core telephony framework to gather information about the SIM card. Use the [subscriberCellularProviderDidUpdateNotifier](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTTelephonyNetworkInfo/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009594-CH1-DontLinkElementID_3) method to get notified about SIM card changes:

> A block object that is dispatched on
>   the default priority global dispatch
>   queue when the user’s cellular
>   provider information changes. This
>   occurs, for example, if a user swaps
>   the device’s SIM card with one from
>   another provider, while your
>   application is running.

Comment: awesome! sounds like a good idea. I will test and update here.